# ios 8 swift - doing stuff after displaying a view

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm working on a app which has a button to open a view that access the camera.
So, I have a button to trigger a segue (using the storyboard) and in my other view, inside `viewDidLoad()`, I'm doing all I need to start the video capture.
The problem is that between touching the button and view been showed it take some small amount of time and I don't like it.
If I comment all the stuff regarding the video capture, the view show up instantly.

So, I think the lag is du to the preparation to access the camera.
How to display the view, an empty view, and then doing the stuff to show the camera?

Comment: do it when the view did appear rather than when it did load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the new view controller and then activate the camera, move your code from `viewDidLoad` into `viewDidAppear`. You could try `viewWillAppear`, but depending on what your code does, you may just see the same issue you have now.

You have to be careful here to only do your activation once as `viewWill/DidAppear` can be called multiple times: especially as a result of being exposed when a controller you push on top is popped.

Comment: Actually, the camera is for a qr code scanner and the view is displayed as modal.

Comment: Updated. Modal works the same way with respect to these functions.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `viewDidAppear` to load all the methods in that view controller instead of using the `viewDidLoad` method like so:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

}
```